# Pandas csv dataframe to json array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file and trying to convert the data into json array.But I am facing issues as "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

The csv file contents are

```
   4.4.4.4
   5.5.5.5
```

My code is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/Documents/datasetfiles/test123.csv', header=None)

df1.head(5)
    0
0   4.4.4.4
1   5.5.5.5


df_to_array = np.array(df1) 
app_json = json.dumps(df_to_array,default=int)
```

I need output as

```
["4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5", "3.3.3.3"]
```

Comment: can you share sample datain test123.csv

Comment: Also in your code you are importing numpy as np and pd as well...

Comment: why not `list(df1[0])`

Comment: @bn_ln list gives values in single quotes ,I need in double quotes as json array

Comment: ok thanks @bn_ln ,i added  as like this and it worked
import json 
df_to_array = list(df1[0])
app_json = json.dumps(df_to_array,default=int)
print(app_json)
["4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5"]

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mentioned, just use `list`: `json.dumps(list(df[0]))`

FYI, the data shape is your problem:

[image]

if you absolutely must use numpy, then transpose the array first:

```py
json.dumps(list(df_to_array.transpose()[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `test.csv`:

```
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

Doing:

```
import json

with open('test.csv') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

print(data)
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Output:

```
['4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5']
["4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5"]
```

You're overcomplicating things using pandas is this is all you want to do~

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/Documents/datasetfiles/test123.csv', header=None)

df1.head(5)
    0
0   4.4.4.4
1   5.5.5.5


df_to_array = list(df1[0]) 
app_json = json.dumps(df_to_array,default=int)

print(app_json)
["4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5", "3.3.3.3"]
```